# JWPlayer: Trying to bound the video player inside my own container

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, jwplayer

I am using the JWPlayer source code for 6.0.2813 (http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/) and It seems the even though I have a movieclip and I added the jwplayer class as a child, the jwplayer creates itself as a child of the main stage, thus allowing it to expand to the bound of the stage and not my movieclip (which I want to be a resizeable/draggable container) in my flash.

I asked the forums for help but they said they never intended it this way and wasn't much help. I was hoping someone familar with the source code could point my in the right direction.

How can I get the JWPlayer to be contained to a movieclip?

Edit:

I made a little bit of progress.

I found the RootReference class in com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/utils/RootReference.as

```
        public function RootReference(displayObj:DisplayObject) {
            if (!RootReference.root) {
                RootReference.root = displayObj.root;
                RootReference.stage = displayObj.stage;
                try {
                    Security.allowDomain("*");
                } catch(e:Error) {
                    // This may not work in the AIR testing suite
                }
            }
        }
```

And noticed that the RootReference.stage is where things get added as a child. `RootReference.stage = displayObj.stage;` where the player class object is sent as displayObj I changed it to be `RootReference.stage = MovieClip(root).gui.video_container;`

Then throughout the code `RootReference.stage.stageHeight` and `RootReference.stage.stageWidth` was used so I switched it to `RootReference.stage.height` and `RootReference.stage.width`. This got it to compile and now the video is within the container but the video's top left is center on my video_container's center and the video isn't resized to the size of my container, but rather the size of the video. Also the controls are completely messed up.

But I was able to resize and move the video around

Comment: Default setting for jwPlayer is to **stretch** the player with black borders. That is done with `uniform` setting.  Also available is `exactfit` and `fill` settings. Here's a [**pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/11vKwQ5M) of what [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) reported while searching all files/sub-folders for `exactfit`.  Perchance changing some of those defaults is better?

Comment: *Correction:* Also available is `none` setting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my testing scenarios are representative of your use-cases, I think I managed to hack up a work around.

The gist of the approach is to replace `RootReference.root` and `RootReference.stage` with a fake stage object that you control. Because most of the jwPlayer classes refer to those static variables instead of their own `root` and `stage` variables, this seems to work, for the most part. What ended up being the most complicated issue was working with the `Stage.stageVideo` objects, which I think are the hardware accelerated video objects. These are always attached to the `stage` and thus weren't compatible with the fake stage object. The main issue with those is positioning, <strike>and I have it mostly worked out, but there is still one glitch which I'll describe later</strike> but it should be ok, now.

The jwPlayer embed script was causing a lot of problems, so to get started I switched to normal SWFObject-based embedding and added a javascript function to the page called `getFlashvars()` that returned the configuration settings. Then, I changed the `com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.utils.Configger.loadExternal()` method to the following:

```
private function loadExternal():void {
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        try {
            //var flashvars:Object = ExternalInterface.call("jwplayer.embed.flash.getVars", ExternalInterface.objectID);
            var flashvars:Object = ExternalInterface.call("getFlashvars");
            if (flashvars !== null) {
                // TODO: add ability to pass in JSON directly instead of going to/from a string
                for (var param:String in flashvars) {
                    setConfigParam(param, flashvars[param]);
                }
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
                return;
            }
        } catch (e:Error) {}
    }
}
```

That's something you probably don't have to deal with per not using a webpage.

The fake stage class is called `StageInterceptor` and is a singleton. To apply it, there were minor changes in the `RootReference` class:

```
package com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.utils {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.system.Security;
    
    // added --------
    import somePackage.StageInterceptor;

    /**
     * Maintains a static reference to the stage and root of the application.
     *
     * @author Pablo Schklowsky
     */
    
    /* Modified for a stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325318/jwplayer-trying-to-bound-the-video-player-inside-my-own-container */
    
    public class RootReference {

        /** The root DisplayObject of the application.  **/ 
        public static var root:DisplayObject;

            // altered --------
        /** A reference to the stage. **/ 
        private static var _stage:StageInterceptor;
        
            // altered --------
        public static function get stage():StageInterceptor {
            return _stage;
        }

        public function RootReference(displayObj:DisplayObject) {
            if (!RootReference.root) {

                    // altered --------
                RootReference.root = StageInterceptor.singleton;
                RootReference._stage = StageInterceptor.singleton;

                try {
                    Security.allowDomain("*");
                } catch(e:Error) {
                    // This may not work in the AIR testing suite
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I removed the `set stage()` setter method from the class.

In the document class, I have the following code. The `MouseEvent.CLICK` handler is to test positioning and re-sizing the movie. The only thing you really need are the first few lines:

```
// add StageInterceptor to the display tree
addChild(StageInterceptor.singleton);
// add the jwPlayer:
var p:Player = new Player();
StageInterceptor.singleton.addChild(p);

// for testing only:
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var stg:StageInterceptor = StageInterceptor.singleton;
    if (e.altKey) {
        // click + alt: ignored (so can play, etc)
        return;
    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
        // click + shift: resizes
        stg.width = e.stageX - stg.x;
        stg.height = e.stageY - stg.y;
    } else {
        // click: moves video
        stg.x = e.stageX;
        stg.y = e.stageY;
    }
});
```

I put `StageInterceptor` in the package `somePackage`. It looks like this:

```
package somePackage
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageVideo;
    
    public class StageInterceptor extends Sprite
    {
        private static var _singleton:StageInterceptor = new StageInterceptor();
        
        public static function get singleton():StageInterceptor {
            return _singleton;
        }
        
        private var _bg:Bitmap;
        
        public function StageInterceptor()
        {
            super();
            
            scrollRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
            
            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500, false, 0);
            _bg = new Bitmap(bmpData);
            _bg.alpha = 0.1;
            _bg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            addChild(_bg);

            if (stage) {
                initOnStage();
            } else {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initOnStage);
            }
        }
        
        private function initOnStage(e:Event = null):void {
            if (e) {
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initOnStage);
            }
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResized);
        }
        
        private function onStageResized(e:Event):void {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
            updateStageVids();
        }
        
        public function updateStageVids():void {
            
            if (stage.stageVideos.length > 0) {
                for each (var sv:StageVideo in stage.stageVideos) {
                    if (!sv.videoWidth || !sv.videoHeight) {
                        continue;
                    } 
                    var rect:Rectangle = stretch(sv.videoWidth, sv.videoHeight, width, height);
                    rect.x = Math.max(0, x + 0.5 * (width - rect.width))
                    rect.y = Math.max(0, y + 0.5 * (height - rect.height));
                    sv.viewPort = rect;
                }
            }
        }
        
        override public function get width():Number {
            return scrollRect.width;
        }
        
        override public function set width(value:Number):void {
            if (value != width) {
                _bg.width = value;
                scrollRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, value, scrollRect.height);
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
                updateStageVids();
            }
        }
        
        override public function set height(value:Number):void {
            if (value != height) {
                _bg.height = value;
                scrollRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, scrollRect.width, value);
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
                updateStageVids();
            }
        }
        
        override public function get height():Number {
            return scrollRect.height;
        }
        
        public function get stageWidth():Number {
            return scrollRect.width;
        }
        
        public function get stageHeight():Number {
            return scrollRect.height;
        }
        
        public function get scaleMode():String {
            return stage.scaleMode;
        }
        
        public function set scaleMode(value:String):void {
            stage.scaleMode = value;
        }
        
        public function get displayState():String {
            return stage.displayState;
        }
        
        public function set displayState(value:String):void {
            stage.displayState = value;
        }
        
        public function get focus():InteractiveObject {
            return stage.focus;
        }
        
        public function set focus(value:InteractiveObject):void {
            stage.focus = value;
        }
        
        public function get stageVideos():* {
            return stage.stageVideos;
        }
        
        override public function set x(value:Number):void {
            if (value != x) {
                super.x = value;
                updateStageVids();
            }
        }
        
        override public function set y(value:Number):void {
            if (value != y) {
                super.y = value;
                updateStageVids();
            }
        }
        
        /**
         * Copied from com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.utils.Stretcher, modified to only
         * do 'uniform' stretch and to return a Rectangle class.
         **/
        public static function stretch(elmW:Number, elmH:Number, availW:Number, availH:Number):Rectangle {
            var scale:Number = Math.min(availW / elmW, availH / elmH);
            elmW = Math.round(elmW * scale);
            elmH = Math.round(elmH * scale);
            return new Rectangle(0, 0, elmW, elmH);
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>The issue that remains has to do with the positioning of video instances when they are initialized. I think simply calling `StageInterceptor.singleton.updateStageVids();` at the right point will do the trick, but I'm not sure.</strike> The edit below covers how this was addressed.

I'm not sure how well this will work if you're not using `stageVideo`. But, with any luck, this will move things in the right direction.

#### Edit:

I've updated the `StageInterceptor` class to do a better job scaling and positioning the video.

Also, it looks like the initial position of videos (at least when it's a stageVideo, is that what you're using?) can be corrected by a small edit in the `com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.media.VideoMediaProvider` class. Adding `import somePackage.StageInterceptor;` to the import statements at the top and then replacing [this line (link to source):](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-6.0/src/flash/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/VideoMediaProvider.as#L255)

`_stage.viewPort = new Rectangle(_media.x,_media.y,_media.width,_media.height);`

To:

`StageInterceptor.singleton.updateStageVids();`

So the method looks like:

```
/** Resize the video or stage.**/
override public function resize(width:Number, height:Number):void {
    if(_media) {
        Stretcher.stretch(_media, width, height, _config.stretching);
        if (_stage) {
            //_stage.viewPort = new Rectangle(_media.x,_media.y,_media.width,_media.height);
            StageInterceptor.singleton.updateStageVids();
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the trick, but I haven't tested it for non stageVideos. And, this update also assumes you're playing videos progressively, not using RTMP media.

#### Edit:

To enable moving and resizing the player with non-StageVideo videos, but still progressively loaded, the contents of the [`com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.view.View.resizeMasker()`](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-6.0/src/flash/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/view/View.as#L491) method need to be either commented out or deleted:

```
protected function resizeMasker():void {
    /*
    if (_displayMasker == null)
        setupDisplayMask();

    _displayMasker.graphics.clear();
    _displayMasker.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);
    _displayMasker.graphics.drawRect(_components.display.x, _components.display.y, _player.config.width, _player.config.height);
    _displayMasker.graphics.endFill();
    */
}
```

I also want to mention the open source version of the jwPlayer is governed under the Creative Commons license, as noted [on their site](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/license):

> JW Player 6 — Open Source Edition
> The use of the JW Player Open Source edition is governed by a Creative Commons license. In short:
>
> JW Player Open Source - You can use, modify, copy, and distribute this edition as long as it's for non-commercial use, you provide attribution, and share under a similar license.
> The license summary and full text can be found here: [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)

Comment: How do you call the somePackage so that RootReference knows of it's existance. Perhaps I am doing it wrong but I have your somePackage as a .as file, and my main class is: http://pastebin.com/11q5BPgN This leads to `RootReference.as, Line 27 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: StageInterceptor.`

Comment: @BHare The *.as file should be named `StageInterceptor.as`. Wherever your the *.as file is for your main class, you can create a folder there called `somePackage` and put `StageInterceptor.as` in that folder. Then, in your main class change, your import statement to `import somePackage.StageInterceptor`. The import statement in `RootReference` should also be `import somePackage.StageInterceptor`.

Comment: Works good, this is what I wanted. I think I just need to add some event handling when the video is moved so that the viewport also changes. Good job.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Awesome. I'm not sure how you're using the jwPlayer, but I tried to set up the `StageInterceptor` to be able to move the video. In my tests, I set the `x`, `y`, `width` or `height` on `StageInterceptor.singleton` and it updated the video. If it's not, it might be that you're not using `Stage.stageVideos`, in which case, there might be a few adjustments necessary.

Comment: No it moves fine but it clips, I think I have to have it update the viewport when it moves. See here for demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Xxg-alAETQ - I'll look into it and probably post an update so that future googlers have a more complete solution. This feature is actually requested a lot, but no one has done code like you

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the ***jwPlayer*** portion of your question since flash is not my forte.

The problem here is [***jwPlayer***](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/about/) is not a simple flash player, but also a **HTML5 Multimedia Player** as well.

---

**Solution 1: SWFObject *embedded* in your Flash Object**

Since ***jwPlayer*** is already compatible with [**SWFObject**](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), use that (i.e., swfobject.js) as a ***mediator*** to load the `player.swf` file (***aka jwPlayer***) into your flash stage. To be sure, ***SWFObject*** acts as a container and will be the "*bounded item*" in your stage, as opposed to using ***jwPlayer*** directly.

Here is an online demo illustrating this solution ***except*** it's using a simple flash video player.

[**Flash Web Site with embedded SWFObject Logo Playing Music Video**](http://www.rockonflash.com)
[**Flash Web Site Documentation on swfObject**](http://www.rockonflash.com/demos/RockOnFlashLogoDemo/asdoc/RockOnFlashLogo/com/rockonflash/papervision3d/utils/SWFObject.html)

Note the [**HTML source page**](http://pastebin.com/Y8M1FpRs) for that flash website shows [**RockOnFlashLogo.swf**](http://www.rockonflash.com/RockOnFlashLogo.swf) as the file being shown in the browsers **entire** viewport. Looking [**deeper**](http://bruce-lab.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/freeswfdecompilers.html), it's written in **AS3**.

Unlike ***jwPlayer v4*** where many ideas floated on the [**internet**](https://www.google.com/search?q=jwPlayer+4.0+embedded+into+flash+site) to embed that version into flash websites due to its lax security, I think you'll have issues with current ***jwPlayer*** license checking, webpage Ready Event Listeners, and popular plugin integration... not to mention issues that may arise from streaming video content.

IMHO, the newer ***jwPlayer*** API and Player are intended to be use via ***webpage installation***.

---

**Solution 2: SWFObject *On-Top* of your Flash Object**

This method treats ***jwPlayer*** how it was meant to be used; as a webpage installation. My motivation came from this online demo for [**Google Chrome Experiment | The Wilderness Downtown**](http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/).

That demo places strategically synchronized browser windows on-top of the main browser window. Although the main browser window is in charge, ***all windows make up the entire experience***. The same method, *but flash flavored*, can be done with your current project with excellent results.

Your Flash Object is in charge and **contains within** an interactive [***frame***](https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=picture+frame) that is allocated for the jwPlayer ***webpage component***. To be sure, this interactive **frame** for ***jwPlayer*** can accept **relocation** (*e.g., via dragging frame edges*) and **resize** (*e.g, frame has [**resize-icon bottom-right**](https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=corner+window+resize)*) which is then relayed to the webpage component (*i.e., `player.swf`*) via **SWFObject** standard embed techniques (*i.e., **location** and **size** set with `jQuery`*).

Here's a basic ***cross-section*** of a webpage for three layered items:

[image]

The **black** layer is the `HTML` of the webpage. The **red** layer is your flash object which contains also has the built-in interactive frame shown in **aqua**. The **green** top layer is the **SWFObject** for **jwPlayer's** `player.swf` file.

***Here's how it would work from jwPlayer to your flash object:***

***1.*** Webpage **jwPlayer API** has **event listener** active and can accept JavaScript.
***2.*** Then **jwPlayer API** receives 'play' status from player, **updates** player event status.
***3.*** Player Event Status is **true** for Play, and therefore **triggers** conditional `if` statement.
***4.*** That `if` statement then **transmits JavaScript** to your flash object, indicating play mode is **true.**
***5.*** Your flash object **receives** this JavaScript of **play** event, and **dims** the stage, **less** the aqua frame.

***Here's how it would work from your flash object to jwPlayer:***

***1.*** The aqua **frame** has user **interaction** when it's moved to left side of stage.
***2.*** Your **AS3** code moves the aqua **frame** accordingly, while **sending** out JavaScript of that location.
***3.*** Webpage **receives** JavaScript and invokes function to position jwPlayer player at **new** location.

***Tip:*** If using a custom **jwPlayer Skin**, incorporate that **skin theme** into your flash object for a **uniform** look.

The benefit of this scenario is that **jwPlayer** maintains ***100% integrity*** while both these flash objects **work in tandem** on your webpage. No hacks, no breakage, no unforeseen consequences, and no headaches... it's standard **jwPlayer API** and **AS3** markup in use.

Hovering over the **jwPlayer** itself is **100% jwPlayer**, while **being bound** to your flash object indirectly.

Comment: One of the main issues I think with your proposed solutions is that you assume the flash will be displayed in a normal browser on a webpage that has access to javascript, which it doesnt. The SWF is to be processed by an application that uses firefox source but is really a 3d game/chat application and is locked down where you cannot run javascript or have any interactivity with the DOM or anything outside the flash object itself.

Comment: (Ran out of room): We upload one .swf file to their server and they will display it within their own rendered viewing window. In this case jwplayer is completely maximized and covers the whole 3d part - which is why I wanted to contain it not to automatically expand.

Comment: Sounds like **Solution 1** is better suited to your application, as *SWFObject* is coded into the main SWF file. Note *SWFObject* loads the simple video player, or in your case that would be `player.swf` file *aka jwPlayer*.

Comment: I've tried every possible solution to try to get access to anything javascript related on the app and couldn't find a way. AFAIK I dont see a way to use SWFObject without the use of javascript so I dont see how **Solution 1** would work.

Comment: Edit: I see you linked to a third party application which uses a flash function named SWFObject, but it only uses the built in SWF loader in flash, which still allows the Jwplayer to hijack the stage and seemingly become it's parent or atleast allow itself to escape any containers

Comment: In Solution 1 there is a link to a SWF file that in turn uses SWFObject in the center portion (i.e., the Logo). That logo can rotate using your mouse. Note that this logo does not use up the entire stage, since SWFObject has limited it's *size and location*, and imports a `video player` playing a video. Also in Solution 1 is a link to an online decompiler to see how that SWF is constructed. On a separate note, jwPlayer is designed to take advantage of the whole stage unless flashvars/flashparams are used. Since that wont work in your app, change the default setting of `uniform` to `exactfit`?

Comment: Using swfobject.js to load the jwPlayer "into your stage" won't work because swfobject.js loads Flash files into a webpage's DOM. The second SWFObject, [this file?](http://bit.ly/Tbqkqw), will allow you to load a swf into a swf, but as BHare pointed out it actually only wraps [`flash.display.Loader`](http://adobe.ly/po7ypA) and suggesting it is synonymous with suggesting [`flash.display.Loader`](http://adobe.ly/po7ypA).

Answer (score 2):

Per your written comments that *JW Player* will not have any access to `JavaScript` and will be using `Firefox Source` that is a specialized `3D Game/Chat Engine` *without* access to any `DOM` elements outside the player, the best solution is to use *JW Player Enterprise Edition*.

That solution will put you in touch with the *Marketing & Engineering* department which can provide a turnkey solution to have JW Player *integrated* into your own product.

*Click the image below* which includes *Licensing* information as well:
 [image]